# Disallow use of certain global variables like JSON with eslint and/or typescript

Tags: typescript, eslint

In short, I want to disallow direct use of `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` and force contributors to use wrapper functions that provide error handling and logging (in my case `stringify/parseJSON()`). If I can disable use of the `JSON` object everywhere, then I can disable any warnings/errors in the files I define the wrapper functions.

#### ESLint

I attempted to do this with the `globals` option in my `.eslintrc.js` like mentioned in the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/language-options#using-configuration-files-1):

```js
    globals: { JSON: "off" },
```

This did nothing with eslint `8.28.0`. It do not even work for `setTimeout` or `Promise` like the docs suggested.

#### TypeScript

I tried to define `JSON` as `null` as a hack for what I want, but the following didn't work even when I made sure the `*.d.ts` file was in the `"include"` section of my `tsconfig.json` (typescript `4.9.3`) ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html)).

```js
declare global {
    var JSON: null;
}
```

---

Neither of those solutions worked for me, and any guidance toward resolving them (or anything to solve my original problem) would be helpful.